# google calendar api - getting undefined for output for gd$where

Tags: javascript, json, google-calendar-api, appcelerator-mobile

i'm able to parse in and display data for all pieces of my code except in this line

```
" where: " + e.gd$where.valueString + // < this line is displaying undefined
```

here is the code block that is doing the processing. everything else displays correct data

```
        Titanium.API.info(cal.feed.entry.length);
    var i;
        for (i=0; i < cal.feed.entry.length; i++){
        var e = cal.feed.entry[i];
        Titanium.API.info("title: " + e.title.$t + 
                        " content " + e.content.$t + 
                        " when: " + e.gd$when[0].startTime + " - " + e.gd$when[0].endTime +
                        " evenstatus" + e.gd$eventStatus.value +
                        " where: " + e.gd$where.valueString + // < this line is displaying undefined
                        " gcal$uid: " + e.gCal$uid.value
                        );
```

here is what should be displayed from the calendar

```
"gd$where": [{
              "valueString": "Any of the 11 elementary schools"
            }],
```

Comment: Can you do console.log(e) (http://getfirebug.com/logging) in firebug to verify that you are trying to access the correct property on gd$where? (do it right after `var e = cal.feed.entry[i];` Once you output that to the console you should be able to click to expand the object and then drill down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gd$where is an array of objects.  In order to access "valueString" in the first key, you need to access it from within that object, like so:

```
gd$where[0].valueString
```